# Group Replication: Transction Hanged

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication, mysql-group-replication

I have configured group replication on mysql 5.7.22 and I found if insert 10k rows then its work fine but once I increase transaction rows upto 20k then its hanged my instance and still not available for any work. I am simple running this statement.

insert into test select * from test1 limit 20000

Comment: I am not a DBA and I used galera cluster that I don't know if it's the same, but When you want to do massive inserts, you need to use bulk mode

Answer (score 0):

You should not use large transactions.

> If an individual transaction results in message contents which are
> large enough that the message cannot be copied between group members
> over the network within a 5-second window, members can be suspected of
> having failed, and then expelled, just because they are busy
> processing the transaction. Large transactions can also cause the
> system to slow due to problems with memory allocation.

You can check the full text on mysql page. [Group Replication Limitations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication-limitations.html)